# What are the current HTML/XHTML/CSS W3C recommended versions?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, w3c, web-standards

What are the latest HTML and CSS specifications officially recommended by the W3C for web development?

I've searched through various sites, W3C included, Only to find Outdated sorces, Or a jumbled goose chase through W3's Site.

Comment: Posted this a little early while adding tags, lemme finish it up T-T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the W3C issues official guidance on which of their specifications you should use but:

The most recent HTML recommendation is [4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/). (HTML [5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) is a candidate recommendation).

The most recent XHTML recommendation is [1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/), but further work on XHTML has been rolled into the HTML work.

The most recent complete CSS specification is [2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/), but CSS [3](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work) consists of various different specifications which reached various different stages of completeness. Some of them are at recommendation level.

---

In practical terms, you should concern yourself more with browser support then the blessing of the W3C.